# Black Screen on Login 12.04.3

Tags: 12.04, lightdm

I've recently installed a fresh version of Ubuntu 12.04.3 Desktop.  At login screen, everything is black except for my mouse cursor and blinking underscore at top left.  I can hear the Ubuntu startup drum sound and can enter desktop by simply entering my password.

I've noticed this starts happening after about the 4th or 5th reboot after install.

```
$ awk '/CRITICAL/ || /WARNING/' /var/log/lightdm/x-0-greeter.log

** (at-spi2-registryd:2210): WARNING **: Failed to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.SessionManager was not provided by any .service files
** (at-spi2-registryd:2210): WARNING **: Unable to register client with session manager
[+0.14s] CRITICAL: g_error_free: assertion `error != NULL' failed
[+0.17s] WARNING: IndicatorObject class does not have an accessible description.
[+0.21s] WARNING: IndicatorObject class does not have an accessible description.
[+0.56s] WARNING: invalid cast from `GtkMenuItem' to `IndicatorMenuItem'
[+0.56s] WARNING: invalid cast from `GtkMenuItem' to `IndicatorMenuItem'
[+0.56s] WARNING: invalid cast from `GtkMenuItem' to `IndicatorMenuItem'
[+0.56s] WARNING: menubar.vala:561: Indicator object 0x83bde8 not in menubar
[+0.56s] WARNING: Getting layout failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface `com.canonical.dbusmenu' on object at path /com/canonical/indicator/users/menu
[+0.80s] CRITICAL: ido_calendar_menu_item_set_date: assertion `IDO_IS_CALENDAR_MENU_ITEM(menuitem)' failed
```

I'm having trouble understanding these errors.

My graphics card is Intel HD 4600 integrated with Haswell CPU.

```
$ sudo lightdm --test-mode
Failed to use bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager, do you have appropriate permissions?
```

Upon looking at `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.DisplayManager.conf` I see:

```
<!-- Only root can own the service -->
<policy user="root">
  <allow own="org.freedesktop.DisplayManager"/>
  <allow send_destination="org.freedesktop.DisplayManager" send_interface="org.freedesktop.DisplayManager" send_member="AddSeat"/>
</policy>
```

What's happening here? Root owns the service, yet I am asked if I have appropriate permissions when accessing as root.

Answer (score 1):

apt-get purge nvidia-prime

that solved the problem for me. Then I registered bumblebee ppa and manually install bumblebee instead.

Comment: If you read the post, you'll see I do not have an NVIDIA graphics card.

Comment: This solved my case, where I don't have `NVIDIA` card either on `Trusty` with Thinkpad t440s.